# Cannot find javax.persistence.AttributeConverter

Tags: java

I have the following import
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
and get a cannot find symbol error in Netbeans.
I have it search Maven and it cannot find any matching results.

My pom dependencies are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-b29</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you try `javax.persistence-2.1.x`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

try this, it worked for me.